# How to combine two ffmpeg command together - Adding Intro Outro and an image in between

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing, video-conversion

I need help in combining two `ffmpeg` commands together.

First command - Insert an image in the middle of a video

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,05,08)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Second command - Insert an image at the begining and end of the video

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i intro.png -i test.mp4 -loop 1 -t 5 -i outro.png -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0][3][1:v][1:a][2][3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

These `ffmpeg` commands works fine individually. But when trying to combine them together always end up in error.

Answer (score 0):

You've to carry out the overlay and then feed that result to the concat filter.

Use

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i intro.png -i test.mp4 -loop 1 -t 5 -i outro.png -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -i image.png -filter_complex "[1][4]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,05,08)'[vid];[0][3][vid][1:a][2][3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4`

Comment: Thank you so much Gyan. It worked and was very helpful. Really appreciate for the quick response.